# Ad banner is not displaying in Chrome

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i've added a JS based banner into my website and it works fine in every browser except for Chrome. Console does not show any errors and i tested it on other sites and it works in Chrome there, so i am really lost here. The banner is supposed to be displayed in the wordpress sidebar.

I am adding the code so you can understand easier but since it is too long i am adding it separately.

Edit: [www.golfklubmagazine.com](https://www.golfklubmagazine.com) under "NAŠI PARTNERJI"

https://js.do/daadoooo113/405147

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Works on my machine (and Chrome).

Comment: I am on a Mac and it does not show. I tried multiple different Macs, iPhones and Huawei phones, and Chrome is the problem on all of these.

Comment: Yeah I am on a Mac too - maybe `Chrome` blocks your ads?

Comment: I went and had a look and JS is allowed. Idk, i ran out of ideas :(

Comment: Also works on my machine. Do you have the link to your wordpress website?

Comment: Edited the original post with the WP link.

Comment: Did you have **Adblocker actived** ??

Comment: @RoyBogado i Did not, the banner shows okay in the fiddle but rejects to show on my WP site in Chrome. Other browsers work fine.

Comment: Possible caching issue? Have you tried emptying cache/history? Tey in incognito mode?  Or added a ?ver=<random number> in the source to trick chrome into loading the file from new?

Comment: I tried all of the above and it still does not work, i am lost. Tried it on multiple devices also.

Comment: I don't know if that's how wordpress works but, your code works fine as a standalone HTML page. In your case your full HTML with its `doctype`,`head` and `body` tags are added into a div. Doesn't that confuse the browser? Maybe just take the relevant parts of your advert HTML and put them in your div?

Comment: If i try to load JS from the server it does not even work in any browsers, but if i load it through <script> code </script> it works everywhere except Chrome. This is really weird. I get no errors in console though.